# Change Firefox Developer Edition top menu from dark blue, back to classic firefox biege?

Tags: firefox

Any way to disable or change the default developer edition (aurora) theme back to original from the dark blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the hamburger menu, click Customize, open the Themes menu and choose Default.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many themes at firefox addons. type this in your browser and you would definitely get what you need. `about:addons`